# ¿Dónde busca Visual Studio Code las definiciones de Laravel?

Tags: visual-studio, xampp

Estoy usando `Visual Studio Code 1.33.1` para editar aplicaciones en `Laravel`. Cuando pulso sobre una palabra clave (como el nombre de una clase) y hago click en **Ir a definición**, VSC me dice que no existe el archivo, pq lo está buscando en una ruta a partir de `C:/xampp`. El problema es que yo ya no tengo xampp. Lo desinstalé y, en su lugar, puse Laragón. He revisado las preferencias de VSC, pero en ningún sitio menciona xampp. No sé como decirle que ahora tiene que buscar a partir de otra ruta.
Alguien sabe donde configurar esto?

Comment: Échale un ojo a https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings y a https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/php

Comment: Gracias, pero lo único que saco en claro de ahí es que hay que tocar en el settings.json, y allí no me aparece nada respecto a la ruta de búsqueda, Si pudieras especificar más te lo agradecería. En las rutas de las variables de entorno tengo puesta la ruta de Laragon. La de Xampp la quité cuando lo desinstalé, así que esa parte sí sé que está bien.

Comment: La configuración de cada *plugin* depende del propio *plugin*. En mi Linux, **todos** los *plugin* están en mi `$HOME/.vscode/NOMBRE-DEL-PLUGIN`. Es cosa de buscarlo ahí.